# Xcode localization sync issue

Tags: string, xcode, localization, catalog

I have a project with two targets, one for the main program and the other for the widget extension. I use the same string catalog file for localization. But I noticed that every time I build, I get two warnings:

Key "CFBundleDisplayName" used with multiple values. Value "First Target" kept. Value "SecondTarget" ignored.

Key "CFBundleName" used with multiple values. Value "FirstTarget" kept. Value "SecondTargetExtension" ignored.

I found that the problem seemed to be caused by the string catalog because I had set it to be the membership of two targets and it was getting the key in both targets to localize, once I removed the widget extension's membership the two warnings disappeared. But I used the same way in another project and didn't get the warning reported. I don't know what is the reason for this?
Can I use different string catalog files in each of the two targets? I tried it and it seems that the newly created string catalog in the widget extension can't get any key, so I failed.
Has anyone else encountered this problem and how do I fix it? It's driving me crazy with it.